# Apache Configuration for Local Server

Tags: apache

I have a development server running Centos 7 I've setup in my living room. As of now I'm not using a domain, my ISP blocks port 80 so I've got Apache listening on port 8080.

I have a few different sites on here I've been playing with. One of them is a redmine installation, another is wordpress, and the other has dolphin on it. I can get any one of these 3 to run normally off the root ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 but when I try to setup an alias it points to the server's local ip. This works great from home, but I can't access them anywhere else.

I've setup a virtual host configuration in apache like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
       Alias /wordpress /var/www/html/wordpress
    </VirtualHost>
```

When I open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/wordpress it tries to redirect to the local ip 192.168.1.xxx:8080/wordpress I feel like I'm on the right track but I'm not sure where to go from here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the solution today after running into something similar with a site I migrated for a client today. I was sure it had to be an apache issue.

The WP installation (and others) were pointing to my private IP as I'm not using domains for any of them. This is why I kept having the site redirect.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.* are [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) addresses. And by definition "IP packets addressed from them cannot be transmitted through the public Internet".
You have to get yourself a public IP or use a service like https://ngrok.com/.

Comment: I have a public IP address. I've setup redmine so it can be accessed via my public ip off port 8080 with

        <VirtualHost *:8080>
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine/public
        </VirtualHost>

And it works great. When I try to access something else that's in a sub-folder of html/ it forwards to the private network address, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

`Alias` directive itself shouldn't cause redirect. There is something else (probably some [Wordpress setting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) or `.htaccess` redirect) that is causing that when the page is opened (or not found)